# how to get the Messages Tab back in version 11.1 Edit->Preferences?

Tags: front-end, customization

On windows 7, version 11.1, when doing edit->Preferences, no longer has the very nice messages tab there any more. I searched but so far, not able to find this tab.

So can't change where my `Print` output go to easily as before, and change other similar settings.

Is it possible to get this tab back? If not, is there other easy way to make same changes? I really do not want to go through advanced setting and go search option inspector and edit things each time I want to make such changes, since I used to change these settings all the time.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know why but:

> [...] Unfortunately removing the Evaluation and Messages tabs in Mathematica 11.1 Preferences is by design. However those settings can be found in our Option Inspector: [...]

Here is an official documentation about that issue:

- [Where are the settings previously found on various Preferences tabs?](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/28318)

---

You can use old preferences dialog but **I can't guarantee everything will be fine:**

```
Module[{relPath, newPath, oldVersion = "11.0"}
  , relPath = Sequence[
        "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd", "SystemResources", "Preferences.nb"
    ]

  ; newPath = FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, relPath}]

  ; If[
        Not @ DirectoryQ @ #
      , CreateDirectory[#, CreateIntermediateDirectories -> True]
    ] & @ DirectoryName @ newPath

  ; CopyFile[
        FileNameJoin[{FileNameDrop @ $InstallationDirectory, oldVersion, relPath}]
      , newPath
    ]

]
```

It copies old dialog to the latest `$UserBaseDirectory` so you don't need to do backup. Just go and delete `newPath` file if anything is wrong.

---

Another way is to play with those options programmatically:

```
CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, PrintAction]
```

> ```
> "PrintToConsole"
> ```

```
Options[$FrontEnd, MessageOptions]
```

> ```
> {MessageOptions -> {"AllowDisablingWarnings" -> True, 
>    "CodeCaptionWarning" -> True, "CompatibilityToolWarning" -> True, 
>    "ConsoleMessageAction" -> "PrintToConsole", 
>    "ErrorAction" -> "PrintToConsole", "ExplainBeepHelp" -> False, 
>    "IgnoreTagBoxDeletionWarning" -> True, 
>    "InsufficientVersionWarning" -> True, 
>    "KernelMessageAction" -> "PrintToConsole", 
>    "MathMLPasteWarning" -> True, "MaxMessageCount" -> 3, 
>    "MessageCountResetTime" -> 2., "TeXPasteWarning" -> True, 
>    "TraditionalFormEvaluationWarning" -> True, 
>    "UseVersionedStylesheetWarning" -> True, 
>    "WarningAction" -> "Beep"}}
> ```

You can set them e.g.:

```
CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, {"MessageOptions", "KernelMessageAction"}] = 
    {"PrintToConsole", "Beep"}
```

Comment: The link is broken, and I fail to find where it's moved to. Anyway it's still available in http://web.archive.org/web/20180913131426/http://support.wolfram.com/kb/28318