# Print[] to console in Mathematica 11

Tags: debugging, command-line

The Edit-> Preferences -> Evaluation menu is gone from Mathematica 11. But I want to redirect the output of `Print` with the option that used to be called

> Print[] command output: Print to Console

How can I set this option now?

Comment: I think it is a duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/140309/5478, let me know if you disagree.

Comment: @Kuba Ah, true! I even favourited that one but could not find it when googling/seaching my activities for "Print[] to console in Mathematica". Feel free to mark it as such.

Answer (score 3):

Run

`SetOptions[$FrontEnd, PrintAction -> "PrintToConsole"]`

The setting will persist across restarts of Mathematica.